# Where is cudaMemset in Alea GPU?

Tags: aleagpu

Where is cudaMemset in Alea GPU?
I want to zero a big array on GPU global memory but I cannot find such function on Alea GPU.

Comment: cudaMemset just uses a `for` statement to index the mem ptr. If you have allocated your memory via AllocateUnified for example, you can just use `UnifiedMemory.Ptr.Set` and a for statement with the `UnifiedMemory .Length` to index over your memory locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to "zero" an array inside a kernel is this:

```
Gpu.Default.Launch(() =>
{
    DeviceRuntime.Zero(YourDeviceMemory, length)
}, new LaunchParam(1, 1));
```